# How add a custom property to SurveyJs question and read its value when answered

Tags: javascript, surveyjs

I'm trying to add a custom property that will hold a boolean for check if a response change should display a popup.

This is a part of my survey.json:

```
{
"type": "radiogroup",
"name": "q1",
"title": {
    "default": "Question number one?"
},
"displayAlert": true,
"isRequired": true,
"choices": [
    {
        "value": "yes",
        "text": {
            "default": "Yes"
        }
    },
    {
        "value": "no",
        "text": {
            "default": "No"
        }
    }
]
```

}

As you can see there is a displayAlert property.

I want to read this property when there is a change in that answer:

```
this.userSurvey.onValueChanging.add((survey: any, change: any) => {
      console.log('alert?', change.question.displayAlert);
    });
```

I've also set this but it don't work:

```
Serializer.addProperty('itemvalue', {
      name: 'displayAlert',
      category: 'general',
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a property not to `itemValue`, but to the `question` type.

```
Survey.Serializer.addProperty("question",
  {
      name: 'displayAlert',
      category: 'general',
    }
)
var json = {
  "pages": [
    {
      "name": "page1",
      "elements": [
        {
        "type": "radiogroup",
        "name": "q1",
        "title": "Question number one?",
        "displayAlert": true,
        "isRequired": true,
        "choices": [
            {
                "value": "yes",
                "text": {
                    "default": "Yes"
                }
            },
            {
                "value": "no",
                "text": {
                    "default": "No"
                }
            }
        ]
        }
      ]
    }] 
};
...
survey.onValueChanging.add(function(survey, change) {
      console.log('alert?', change.question.displayAlert);
});
```

Try this example: https://plnkr.co/edit/ggW5NkqCWdoSHfZ6.